# How to abort all DB save operations inside of a given block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm implementing a public live demo functionality into our web app.

Since this is a public demo, we don't want any DB changes to take effect (to prevent abuse), instead they'd just run successfully but nothing touches the DB.

Something like:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController   
  def update
    disable_save_operations if @current_account.live_demo?

    @post = Post.find params[:id]
    @post.update_attributes params[:post]
  end
end
```

Ideally I'd like to keep the same functionality but silently trash any UPDATE, DELETE, or INSERT queries and not actually process them.

How can I do something like this?

Comment: What do you mean 'run successfully'?  You want the operation to fail but return true?

Comment: Sounds like you should forgo a database all together, and do something session-local.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested but I believe what you want to do can be done like this.

```
def rollback_if_demo(&block)
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    yield
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback if @current_account.live_demo?
  end
end
```

Then just call it like this

```
rollback_if_demo do
  @post = Post.find params[:id]
  @post.update_attributes params[:post]
end
```